# Keep getting java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException error on my jpql

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql, websphere-liberty, postgresql-9.6

Keep getting this error when I try to fetch all records for an entity from the database.

```
[err] javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.1.v20171221-bd47e8f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.getLargeUpdateCount is not yet implemented.
Error Code: 0
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Vehicle sql="VEHICLE_ID", "NAME" FROM "VEHICLES"")
[err]   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:389)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at com.ibm.op.model.control.vehicles.VehicleScheduler.retrieveVehiclesAtStartUp(VehicleScheduler.java:74)
[err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[err]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[err]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[err]   at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invokeProceed(EJSContainer.java:4870)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[err]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[err]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[err]   at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InterceptorProxy.invokeInterceptor(InterceptorProxy.java:200)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[err]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[err]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[err]   at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InterceptorProxy.invokeInterceptor(InterceptorProxy.java:200)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[err]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here's the code:

```
@Table(name="\"VEHICLES\"")
@Entity
public class Vehicle {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name="\"VEHICLE_ID\"")
    private Long id;


    @NotNull
    @Column(name="\"NAME\"")
    private String name;

    //... Getters and setters
}

@Stateless
public class VehicleScheduler{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    @PostConstruct
    public void retrieveVehiclesAtStartUp() {
        try {
            List<Vehicle> vehicles = this.entityManager
                .createQuery("SELECT v FROM Vehicle v", Vehicle.class)
                .getResultList();
            vehicles.forEach((vehicle) -> {
                System.out.println("We got new vehicle " + vehicle.getId());
            });
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="local" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/postgres</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Where `jdbc/postgres` is the jndi lookup name that we configure in the websphere-liberty server.xml file. I am using jpa-2.2, eclipselink-2.7.1, postgresql-42.2.2.jar for jdbc driver and postgresql-9.6 database server.The list of features in server.xml is

```
   <featureManager>
        <feature>beanValidation-2.0</feature>
        <feature>cdi-2.0</feature>
        <feature>appSecurity-3.0</feature>
        <feature>j2eeManagement-1.1</feature>
        <feature>wasJmsServer-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jaxrs-2.1</feature>
        <feature>webProfile-8.0</feature>
        <feature>jcaInboundSecurity-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jsonb-1.0</feature>
        <feature>managedBeans-1.0</feature>
        <feature>ejbHome-3.2</feature>
        <feature>jaxws-2.2</feature>
        <feature>jsonp-1.1</feature>
        <feature>jaxrsClient-2.1</feature>
        <feature>el-3.0</feature>
        <feature>concurrent-1.0</feature>
        <feature>appClientSupport-1.0</feature>
        <feature>ejbRemote-3.2</feature>
        <feature>jaxb-2.2</feature>
        <feature>mdb-3.2</feature>
        <feature>jacc-1.5</feature>
        <feature>batch-1.0</feature>
        <feature>json-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jaspic-1.1</feature>
        <feature>distributedMap-1.0</feature>
        <feature>websocket-1.1</feature>
        <feature>wasJmsSecurity-1.0</feature>
        <feature>wasJmsClient-2.0</feature>
        <feature>ejbLite-3.2</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jdbc-4.2</feature>
        <feature>jpa-2.2</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jpaContainer-2.2</feature>
    </featureManager>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is the JPQL query not executing correctly?

I did find this in the websphere liberty profile logs

```
Exception = java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException
Source = com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.v42.WSJdbc42PreparedStatement.closeWrapper
probeid = 310
Stack Dump = java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.getLargeUpdateCount is not yet implemented.
    at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:683)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.getLargeUpdateCount(PgStatement.java:998)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.postgresql.ds.PGPooledConnection$StatementHandler.invoke(PGPooledConnection.java:428)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.getLargeUpdateCount(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.v42.WSJdbc42PreparedStatement.getCompatibleUpdateCount(WSJdbc42PreparedStatement.java:51)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.impl.DatabaseHelper.getUpdateCount(DatabaseHelper.java:336)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.closeWrapper(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:306)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcObject.close(WSJdbcObject.java:152)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcObject.close(WSJdbcObject.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.closeStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.releaseStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1700)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:709)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2093)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2740)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2693)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1221)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:911)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1268)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2979)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1892)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1874)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:480)
    at com.ibm.op.model.control.vehicles.VehicleScheduler.retrieveVehiclesAtStartUp(VehicleScheduler.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invokeProceed(EJSContainer.java:4870)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:651)
    at com.ibm.ws.cdi.ejb.impl.InterceptorChain.proceed(InterceptorChain.java:119)
    at com.ibm.ws.cdi.ejb.impl.EJBCDIInterceptorWrapper.invokeInterceptors(EJBCDIInterceptorWrapper.java:131)
    at com.ibm.ws.cdi.ejb.impl.EJBCDIInterceptorWrapper.aroundTimeout(EJBCDIInterceptorWrapper.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InterceptorProxy.invokeInterceptor(InterceptorProxy.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:631)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:81)
    at com.ibm.ws.cdi.ejb.interceptor.WeldSessionBeanInterceptorWrapper.aroundInvoke(WeldSessionBeanInterceptorWrapper.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InterceptorProxy.invokeInterceptor(InterceptorProxy.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:631)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.doAroundInterceptor(InvocationContextImpl.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.doAroundInvoke(InvocationContextImpl.java:272)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invoke(EJSContainer.java:4772)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.TimedObjectWrapper.invokeCallback(TimedObjectWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.TimerNpRunnable.doWork(TimerNpRunnable.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.TimerNpRunnable.run(TimerNpRunnable.java:102)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: can you show the full stack trace?  (found in messages.log, will not have internal classes hidden from stack).  Also, can you post your feature list in server.xml?

Comment: Added the features. But couldn't find the messages.log.

Comment: I found a stacktrace in the Websphere liberty profile's logs and added them at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Thanks for uploading the full stack trace.  This looks like a bug in WebSphere Liberty code.  Can you open an issue at https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty?

Comment: Thanks Andy. I am talking to the was-liberty team directly on slack as I work at IBM. Hopefully it will get fixed soon. :fingers_crossed:

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the PostgreSQL source code, the JDBC driver claims to be JDBC 4.2 compliant:

https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/util/DriverInfo.java

However, it has not implemented new JDBC 4.2 methods.  In this case, `Statement.getLargeUpdateCount()`:
https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/jdbc/PgStatement.java#L997

So there is no way the EclipseLink could know ahead of time if calling `Statement.getLargeUpdateCount()` will work or not (since the driver says it's 4.2 compliant).  However, EclipseLink probably could be handling the SQLFeatureNotSupported exception better that `PgStatement.getLargeUpdateCount()` is throwing.  Updating your question with the full stack trace would help diagnose the problem more accurately.

Comment: There isn't any more stacktrace. The above stacktrace keeps repeating.

Comment: logical result - use older JDBC version

Comment: Older JDBC version doesn't work with javaee-8.0 in Websphere liberty. I am just to Glassfish and hoping that it won't fail.